# Unterminated string literal with PHP in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Please tell me why this code tells me

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

My code:

```
<script>
console.log(" <?php $geladen = file_get_contents("./testtext"); echo $geladen; ?> ");

</script>
```

Comment: look at the rendered output, you more than likely have other quotes (`"`) within your echoed content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a JavaScript error message, which strongly implies one of two things:

1. the JavaScript that reaches the browser still includes the `<?php` etc., meaning the PHP didn't get parsed on the server (and thus the browser flipped out on `"./testtext"`), or
2. the file `testtext` (and therefore your variable `$geladen`) contains quotation marks. Either is possible from the very little information you have posted.

You can figure out which it is by looking at the HTML in your browser.

If it's the former (if you see `<?php` in the HTML), then you need to fix your server configuration.

If it's the latter (if `testtext` contains any `"` marks), then you need to encode it properly before echoing, using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like this:

```
<script>
console.log(" <?php $geladen = file_get_contents("./testtext"); echo json_encode($geladen); ?> ");

</script>
```

All that said, mixing PHP and HTML (not to mention PHP, HTML, *and JavaScript*) this way is not a great practice. You'd be much better off using a templating engine of some sort (Twig, Blade, etc.).

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of 'testtext' contains a quote mark, it will break the javascript. Try addslashes().

```
<script>
console.log(" <?php $geladen = addslashes(file_get_contents("./testtext")); echo $geladen; ?> ");
</script>
```

Comment: it just contains
Hello World!